# Progress Bar Visibility reset after I start interacting with UI when using motion layout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

ConstraintLayout version: 2.0.0-alpha3

So I am using MotionLayout I wanted to create something similar to this. https://blog.stylingandroid.com/motionlayout-collapsing-toolbar-part-2/

I want to achieve When the user enters activity there is `ProgressBar` spinning when I load data (takes some time) I want `ProgressBar` to hide.

My problem is that when I start interacting with UI `ProgressBar` state is reset and is visible again

What should I do to prevent progressBar to start showing after the user starts interacting with it?

Here is a simplified version

**`layout file`**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/collapsing_toolbar"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showPaths="true">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_image">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2000dp"
                android:background="#ff2"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error"
        android:text="ERROR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Here is layout description (**`xml/collapsing_toolbar`**)

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/scroll_view"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top"/>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

and this is a simple activity where I hide ProgressBar after 1second

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
            error.text="NEW ERROR"
            error.visibility = View.GONE
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

I am using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3`

**EDIT:** I also reported this as bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124812189

**EDIT:** partial solution for this is to set progress_bar and error visibility to GONE << However the same scenario applies here so if you interact with loading you can see `scrollView`, but it's better than to see ProgressBar when there should be content.

Comment: I think Nicolas mentioned somewhere (might have been this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8cYDlBOPaA&feature=youtu.be) that this is a bug that they are aware of and it will be fixed in alpha 4 (which is said to be released in the coming weeks). Pinging @camaelon on Twitter might also help.

Comment: @jossiwolf thanks a lot, I was hoping for it to be a bug, not my abuse of their API.

Comment: He is talking about it around https://youtu.be/r8cYDlBOPaA?t=2276

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android:visibility changes to children of MotionLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57168071/androidvisibility-changes-to-children-of-motionlayout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is now fixed! Go and live your merry life without any visibility glitches :)

For future readers: This was known bug in MotionLayout where the state reset when the user touched something. Nicolas is talking about this around here: https://youtu.be/r8cYDlBOPaA?t=2276

The team fixed it in Alpha 4.

Comment: Don't forget to update your answer after alpha4 is out :)

Comment: I think it's time :)

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get a work around for this issue until alpha4 is released.

In my use case I have a  button which is normally only shown when a list is in end it mode. So to keep it hidden when the list isn't in edit mode I'm changing the constraints based on the edit mode.

```
 private void enableDoneButton(boolean enabled){
    int visibility = enabled ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
    ConstraintSet startSet = container.getConstraintSet(R.layout.fragment_menu);
    startSet.setVisibility(R.id.fab_done, visibility);
}
```

Hope this helps in the meantime.