# MotionLayout OnSwipe transition glitch when first time swipe at the opposite direction

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I am using MotionLayout to achieve a simple animation: I have two views inside my MotionLayout, a bar constrained to top and a RecyclerView constrained to the bottom of the bar. When I am scrolling the RecyclerView, the top view should be pushed out. (Like a collapsing toolbar) My MotionScene looks like the following:

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start">

    <OnSwipe
        motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
        motion:moveWhenScrollAtTop="false"
        motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/table_view" />

</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/table_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filters" />

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/filters"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/table_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/filters"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:translationY="-48dp"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</ConstraintSet>
```

The *filters* is the top view and the *table_view* is the RecyclerView. The animation is working like a charm with only a pretty big glitch. When I first enter the screen and start dragging the RecyclerView **down**, the whole top view is disappearing. If I start scrolling up, everything is back to normal and I cannot reproduce the glitch anymore. I don't know if I am doing something wrong, or there is a bug in the MotionLayout.

*Notes:* I needed the **transitionY** for specific purposes. If I change the OnSwipe direction to *dragDown*,  the same thing is happening when I start to scroll up.

Comment: This is a known bug in MotionLayout, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788747/progress-bar-visibility-reset-after-i-start-interacting-with-ui-when-using-motio for reference. It will be fixed in Alpha 4 which Nicolas mentioned is expected to be released this month.

Comment: Seems like it was completely fixed in Beta 3 :)