# android:visibility changes to children of MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I must be missing something with android:visibility changes within a motion layout. Here’s a simplified version of my layout.

```
<MotionLayout>
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/HeaderBackground" />
Bunch of image views, Text views that are constrainted to the HeaderBackground. 
<RecyclerView android:visibility="visible">
<EditText android:visibility="visible">
<CustomViewGroup1 android:visibility="gone">
</MotionLayout>
```

I have a motionScreen that sets a Transition onswipe based on the recycler view to reduce the height of the HeaderBackground and hide some of the images/text views (i.e a collasping toolbar).
However, if there’s some fatal error, I want to show CustomViewGroup1 on top/infront of the RecyclerView but toggling the visibility of the RecyclerView to gone and CustomViewGroup1 to visible doesn’t make the CustomViewGroup1 show.

I could move the CustomViewGroup group out of the MotionLayout and add a framelayout as the root of the activity and hide the whole MotionLayout. But this is less than ideal as I’d have to copy of the toolbar bar and icons. So I guess the question is about visibility changes and potentially z ordering?

I'm using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2`

Comment: Went through same issue, worked around with alpha

Comment: @RameesThattarath to clarify you switched back to alpha and that resolved the issue? if so which version.

Comment: androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1

Comment: hmm... thanks for reply. However, I get the same behaviour between `2.0.0-beta1` and `2.0.0-beta2`.

Answer (score 116):

Turns out this was my inexperience with how MotionLayout works. By default MotionLayout controls the visibility of all views within it. But you can opt out child views by using the `app:visibilityMode="ignore"` attribute **and** defining the view in the `<ConstraintSet>`

In my case `<CustomViewGroup1>` looks like this...

```
<Constraint
      android:id="@id/CustomViewGroup1"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/HeaderBackground"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
      app:visibilityMode="ignore" />
```

And this is defined the same in **both** collasped and expended ConstraintSets as I don't want it to move/animation when the recycler view is scrolled.

Thanks to John Hoford for the advice in another channel.

Comment: Thank you. This has been my saviour after days of search to fix it.

Comment: motion:visibilityMode="ignore" worked for me

Answer (score 50):

My approach is to exclude the view from the motion layout, ignore the visibility from the scene so it can be programmatic and also inherit the constraints in the end constraint set.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout#additional_motionlayout_attributes) mentioned the `app:applyMotionScene="boolean"` but it doesn't tell you where. It has to be in a `PropertySet`

Also `visibilityMode` only worked for me inside a `PropertySet` as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        ...
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint android:id="@id/viewId">
            <PropertySet
                app:applyMotionScene="false"
                app:visibilityMode="ignore" />
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/end"
        motion:deriveConstraintsFrom="@id/start">
        ...
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

**Careful with the app namespace auto-import from motion scene, that one is wrong** you have to use the same that is used on the layouts.

The benefit of this is:

- No width, height or constraints in the scene
- No need to repeat the properties since is derived from the start constraint set

Comment: Mahn!!! You saved me... applyMotionScene was the real deal. I saw it on the documentation but it didn’t make any real sense to me... Oh thanks

Comment: @PaulOkeke check this serie https://youtu.be/o8c1RO3WgBA and welcome glad to help

Answer (score 9):

Programmatically way

```
View clickableArea = motionLayout.findViewById(R.id.video_overlay_thumbnail);    
motionLayout.getConstraintSet(R.id.start).getConstraint(clickableArea.getId()).propertySet.mVisibilityMode = 1; // 1 - ignore or 0 - normal
clickableArea.setVisibility(GONE);
```

Comment: Very nice.. Work perfectly!! thanks :)

Comment: this doesn't work under observe for me whereas outside observe it's working.For eg: viewModel.messageLinkedList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {//doesn't works here}

Answer (score 4):

You can change visibility children of Motion layout promatically, by this way:

```
fun View.changeVisibility(visibility: Int) {
        val motionLayout = parent as MotionLayout
        motionLayout.constraintSetIds.forEach {
            val constraintSet = motionLayout.getConstraintSet(it) ?: return@forEach
            constraintSet.setVisibility(this.id, visibility)
            constraintSet.applyTo(motionLayout)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Set ***visibilityMode*** property to ***normal***, working fine for me with *`2.0.0-beta3`*.

```
 app:visibilityMode="normal"
 android:visibility="visible"
```

Comment: it's normal by default

Answer (score 3):

The other option depending on your use case is to make sure the view you want to control the visibility of isn't a direct descendant of the MotionLayout. Place it in a container view and you'll be able to set the visibility as normal

Answer (score 1):

According to Mr. Albert's answer, which is the good one, I would like to suggest another solution. Setting the `PropertySet` value programmatically may lead to `java.lang.NullPointerException` when the phone configuration is changed (for example switching Night Mode). So it would be better to add a `Constraint` with `PropertySet` in your Motion Layout's "scene" file instead:

```
     <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            //some of scene constraints
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint>
            //some of scene constraints
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint android:id="@+id/ivEdit"> //id of your view to change visibility
            <PropertySet
                app:visibilityMode="ignore"/>
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>
```