# Android visibility not working for MotionLayout

Tags: android, layout, data-binding, observer-pattern, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to make visibility changes for a view under MotionLayout using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62658424/5412554
but for me, it's not working under observe. For eg:

```
viewModel.messageLinkedList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
binding.motionLayout.getConstraintSet(R.id.start).getConstraint(binding.deleteAllText.id).propertySet.mVisibilityMode = 1; // 1 - ignore or 0 - normal
binding.deleteAllText.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

If I use simply in onCreateView of fragment it works.

For eg:

```
binding.motionLayout.getConstraintSet(R.id.start).getConstraint(binding.deleteAllText.id).propertySet.mVisibilityMode = 1; // 1 - ignore or 0 - normal
binding.deleteAllText.visibility = View.GONE
```

Please help me with the correct solution.

Comment: have you tried the `app:visibilityMode="ignore"` in your xml? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216827/9658449

Comment: yes have tried this too but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it works with data-binding but I found a Solution for Kotlin, maybe you can something figure out:

```
motion_layout_id.getConstraintSet(R.id.start)?.let {
            it.setVisibility(R.id.deleteAllText, View.GONE)
            motion_layout_main.requestLayout() // this must be done to apply the visibility change
        }
```