# Issue with TextView visibility when setting multi-line text in Android MotionLayout layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-motionlayout

I'm encountering an issue with a simple Android layout containing a `Button` and a `TextView`. Initially, the `TextView` is hidden, and upon clicking the button, I set its visibility to `VISIBLE` and populate it with text.

However, I'm facing a peculiar behavior: when I set a single-line text, the `TextView` appears correctly upon clicking the button. But when I set a multi-line text, the `TextView` doesn't show up on the first click; instead, I need to click the button twice to make it visible.

Here's a minimal example of my code:

main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

        button.setOnClickListener {

            //textView.setText("Some dummy text") // it works

            // not working
            textView.setText("Some dummy text jtext text text text texte text texte txjkk ggg gggg ggggg gg trdff rrrrrr rrrr")

            textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main_scene.xml

```
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

- I've tried changing the order of setting the text and making the `TextView` visible, but it didn't help.
- I also tried forcing the layout to refresh using `textView.invalidate()`, but the problem remains.
- If I replace the MotionLayout with ConstraintLayout, it works correctly.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the issue in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57168071/androidvisibility-changes-to-children-of-motionlayout) post. I fixed it by placing the `TextView` inside the scene and added `motion:visibilityMode="ignore"` like this:

```
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```